# For any nonzero $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, there exist $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, such that $x^*Ax\neq0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that $\sup\limits_{{x\in\mathbb{C}^n:\,\|x\|_2=1\\}} |x^*Ax|$ is a norm.

How to show that for any given nonzero $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, there exist $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, such that $\|x\|_2=1$ and $x^*Ax\neq0$?

It is easy to construct $x$ for given $A$, but not obvious for general $A$.

Comment: Maybe you can choose an eigenvector for a nonzero eigenvalue

Comment: What about $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$ ?

Comment: @pyrogen this would work if A has a non-zero eigenvalue which is not necessarily given

Comment: @kimchilover We have $\pmatrix{\bar x&\bar y}\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\bar xy-x\bar y$ which is not necessarily 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^*Ax=0$ for all $x$, then we get
$$0\ =\ (x+y)^*A(x+y)\ =\ \overbrace{x^*Ax}^0 + y^*Ax + x^*Ay + \overbrace{y^*Ay}^0\ =\ y^*Ax+x^*Ay\\
0\ =\ (x+iy)^*A(x+iy)\ =\ -i\cdot y^*Ax + i\cdot x^*Ay$$
So, $y^*Ax-x^*Ay=0$, together with $y^*Ax+x^*Ay=0$, it yields $y^*Ax=x^*Ay=0$.

Since $y^*Ax$ holds for all $y$, we get $Ax=0$.

Comment: $ A$ is not hermitian so polarisation identity tells us $y^*Ax+x^*Ay=y^*(A+A^*)x=0$